# Is there an optimal order to play through?

Tags: alpha-protocol

In Alpha Protocol, after Operation Desert Spear, there are three main mission hubs: operation Blood Feud (Moscow), operation True Heirs (Taipei), and operation Deus Vult (Rome). To avoid spoilers, I know that certain people can help deal with other enemies, certain vendors can be unlocked earlier, and certain people are displeased, depending on the order in which the missions are tackled. What are all the things that I should do in a certain order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Alpha Protocol wiki article](http://alphaprotocol.wikia.com/wiki/Beneficial_Mission_Order) lists a very optimized mission order. However, be warned that it is pretty spoiler filled, and honestly, there's no way to explain *exactly* what you have to do without spoiling at least *some* of the game.

Basically, the optimal mission order involves starting with Moscow, and jumping to Taipei before a certain point to make finishing Moscow easier. Once you've finished Moscow, you can do either Taipei or Rome as they don't really affect one another in a significant way.

Through my personal playthroughs of the game, I've found that I prefer to to the mission hubs one at a time, starting with Rome, going to Taipei, and finishing with Moscow. It seems to create an optimal difficulty curve, as the missions in Moscow and Taipei can be a bit overwhelming for a lower level character.

Comment: Aha, I know what you're referring to in the second paragraph.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to be as vague as possible. I wasn't sure if you were doing a first playthrough or not, plus I'd hate to spoil this game for someone who has never played it.